# Art tool or artistic tool?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, usage

> I want to study the usage of language as an artistic/art tool.

What word should I choose here? It seems that 'art tool' is somewhat more common, although its meaning is very literal (e.g. art tools include brushes, pencils, etc.), which confuses me.

Comment: You should indicate what you mean. Do you mean that language is used to make art, is a work of art, is similar to art, is used to convey ideas about art, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *artistic medium*.

> Artistic medium is a term that is used by artists and art critics to refer to that out of which a work of art or, more generally, a particular art form, is made.

Source: [Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy](https://iep.utm.edu/artistic-medium/)

Sometimes the term *artist's medium* is used instead.

One challenge with this word is that historically the plural of *medium* was *media*, but the term *media* has become so commonly used to refer to news and entertainment venues that people don't connect it with the term *medium* any longer. So you will often see *mediums* used instead. Which plural you use is up to you, but some of your audience will probably think you are wrong either way.

Comment: I like this answer. I also don't see a problem with the plural "media" since it's only used singularly in the context, and "medium" is never used to describe news media.

Answer (score -1):

Art tools are tools to create art (e.g. tools for drawing or painting).

[image]

An artistic tool is just a tool that stands out, is designed well, creative, inventive, original, or has any other property that art usually represents.

One can have an artistic bootle opener.

[image]

Art tools are inherently artistic: they often look beautiful, colourful and inspire their owner.

Comment: Thanks, I caught the difference!